# kotlin: set default values for a parent class

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I am trying to achieve the most concise combination for a parent and a child class in Kotlin.

This is like my classes look like.

```
sealed class Parent {
 open val attribute : String = "initial value"
}

data class Child (
  override val attribute: String
) : Parent ()
```

I would like to have the `attribute` value set as `"initial value"` if the constructor Child() is empty.

And I would like to have an opportunity to set the `attribute` value of a `Child`-object through the constructor if I want it to be something else (not equal to `"initial value"`)

Is it possible in Kotlin?

Comment: do you want to do this specifically with a **data class**?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to have your subclass reuse the initial value from the superclass (which was a valid answer until the `data class Child` appeared):

```
sealed class Parent(val attribute : String = "initial value")

class Child : Parent {
  constructor() : super()
  constructor(attribute: String) : super(attribute)
}
```

This way cou can now call either your default constructor of the `Child` which will result in `"initial value"` or pass an appropriate attribute instead. However this will not work with a `data class Child` as you need to have a primary constructor there.

The following will set the attribute to `"initial value"` when calling the "default" `Child`-constructor:

```
sealed class Parent {
  open val attribute : String = "initial value"
}

data class Child (override val attribute: String) : Parent() {
  constructor() : this("initial value")
}
```

In fact it's rather a secondary constructor.
As you can only call super constructors if you do not have a primary in the subclass, your remaining options are rather small. You may want to redesign your class hierarchy or just hold some constant somewhere.

Comment: yes, it is possible. But the initial value of a parent class does not help at all. And i hoped that it can play somehow.

Comment: But you override it. Maybe you want another construct instead? I updated my answer to show you a way to reuse the `super.attribute` instead

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your `data class`-usage.